# Merging two audio files takes more time on Nexus

Tags: android, audio, merge

In my project I am working on audio and call recording functionality. I need to merge two audio files. For merging i have written following code:

```
     try {
        FileInputStream fistream1 = new FileInputStream(file1); // first
        // source  file
        FileInputStream fistream2 = new FileInputStream(file2);// second
        // source file
        SequenceInputStream sistream = new SequenceInputStream(fistream1, fistream2);

        File audioDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), CONSTANTS.PATH_TO_MERGED_AUDIO);
        if (!audioDir.exists()) {
            audioDir.mkdirs();
        }
        FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream(audioDir + "/mergedFile.wav");// destinationfile

        int temp;

        while ((temp = sistream.read()) != -1) {
            fostream.write(temp); // to write to file
        }
        fostream.close();
        sistream.close();
        fistream1.close();
        fistream2.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Now, Problem is i am running this  code over Note3 OS 4.0.1 , it is working fine. But when i run same code over Nexus4 OS 5.0.1. It takes 5-6 minutes, as compared to Note3. I search on this but dint found any result. PLease help me where I am doing wrong or do I need to implement another API for merging two audio files.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error message? What goes wrong?

Comment: @martin: i hve two files. One file is of 1min and another file is of 30 sec. For merging these files it is taking near abt 5-6 min, ie. much more for merging.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving answer to my own question. I solved this problem. Initially i was in doubt that error might be hardware specific. but the issue was the way I was writing file.

```
           byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
           try {
             for (int readNum; (readNum = sistream.read(buf)) != -1;)
                 fostream.write(buf, 0, readNum);
             } finally {
             if(sistream!=null){
                 sistream.close();
             }

         }
```